# flex:Can we develop flex mobile project that runs in both android and iphone

Tags: iphone, android, apache-flex

Can we develop flex mobile project  that runs in both android and iphone.Also I want to know , can we use all the device capabilities of both android and iphone in same project

Comment: Voted to close because user didn't do any research.

Comment: Yes.  Yes you can.  Flex is magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://gregsramblings.com/2011/04/26/convincing-developers-that-adobe-flex-rocks-on-android-ios-and-playbook/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve that with the new Flex SDK 4.5.1, then when you develop one app in Flash Builder and then build it on both Android and iPhone or even on Blackberry tablets. You can also add different styles to Android and iOS (for example different colors, buttons, everything...).

Download: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flexsdk

For building the actual app you will need an Apple developer certificate or you can always download a fake one from the internet that works just as well.